# Name that printing file format

Tags: printing, file-format, xps, printer-control-language, epl

Hello there fellow Stackers!

I wonder if anybody could tell me what the following file format is? If you print it as-is then your print out will be, er, as-is BUT if you send it *directly* to the printer (for example using NET USE in a DOS/Windows batch file) it will actually print a very nice Parcelforce posting label:

---

```
:Printer Setting...
WN
N
R0,0
N
I8,0,061
S2
D9
ZT
Q1242,020
:Carrier Logo...
GG50,1060,"BLOB400"
:Service Indicator...
A775,1160,2,A,1,1,N,""
LO530,975,290,4
LO530,975,4,232
:739 bullet (type 1)...
A125,1005,1,1,1,1,N,"739"
A455,1030,2,4,1,1,N,"PB PI3749824 001"
:Despatch Date...
A270,935,2,3,1,1,N,"Despatch Date/Day"
A270,915,2,3,1,1,N,"16/09/10, Thu"
:Address Info...
A795,915,2,4,1,1,N,"MR STACK OVERFLOW"
A795,885,2,4,1,1,N,"CPU LANE"
A795,855,2,4,1,1,N,"COMPUTER CASE"
A795,825,2,4,1,1,N,"UK "
A795,795,2,5,1,1,N,"90210"
:Parcel Number...
A460,980,2,4,1,2,N,"1"
A360,980,2,4,1,2,N,"1"
A400,980,2,4,1,1,N,"OF"
:Bar-coded Postcode...
B330,885,2,1,3,4,170,N,"*90210*"
```

---

Is it XPS or PCL or something? Printer-specific? Any thoughts or answers would be appreciated! Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's XPS or PCL.

It appears to have a lot in common with HPGL.

I think I found it; it appears to be [EPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eltron_Programming_Language).

Comment: Thanks you! Your answer was speedy and correct (by all accounts). Thanks a lot. You're the dog now man!!!

Comment: Please consider marking the answer as 'accepted' by clicking on the checkmark.  This helps make it clear what worked for you, and I get a few reputation points out of it. ;)